# Website not available after publishing

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-6, web-applications

We use Windows 10 with IIS10 for developing my webapps in Visual Studio 2019.

Now I've published my working dev site to the production server running IIS 6.2 on Windows Server 2012.  However, when started, the site isn't available, not even if I start it from IIS using it's local address.

The site is running and the application pool is started for this site and the bindings are correct.

Even if I add a simple test.html page with nothing special, I can't load that page.

I've upgraded .net on the server to 4.8, and the site targets 4.7.2.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Duh.  I forgot to add it to the server's DNS Forward Lookup Zone.